# How do I export data from Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I am developing with Firebase and have data stored in the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/). I need to share my database structure for a question here on Stack Overflow, or just take a backup before making breaking changes. How can I do this using the Firebase Console?

Comment: This isn't covered in the documentation, so I've added this Q&A-style so it can be linked to in comments.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Data can be exported from the Firebase Realtime Database as JSON:

1. Login to the [Database section of the Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).
2. Navigate to the node you wish to export by clicking on it in the list (skip this to export all data).
3. Click the 3-dot overflow menu icon, at the top-right of the data panel.
4. Click `Export JSON` from the menu.

   [image: console menu screenshot]

Likewise, you can import a structure in the same fashion, using `Import JSON`.

Comment: I have a 600MB database that I wanted to export but it doesn't lets me export that database and gives a Payload too large error

Comment: @IshanJain see my answer for jsons too big for the console https://stackoverflow.com/a/49529584/2327328

Comment: I found a solution to my problem the day after I put my comment here. But Thanks for your suggestion, I'll try this tool if I am in a similar situation. @philshem

Comment: if it's not covered in this page, post your answer for the next curious person

Comment: Can you tell me what is the use of exporting database as JSON?

Comment: @RohitSingh - running *ad hoc* analytics, moving DB to another project (test/dev/live), etc

Answer (score 12):

There is an Node.js tool called [`firebase-export`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-export), similar to [`firebase-import`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-import) but not from Firebase itself, that will export JSON from the command line.

> Firebase export helper utility for exporting excluded JSON from Firebase.

To install

```
npm install -g firebase-export
```

Usage example

```
$ firebase-export --database_url https://test.firebaseio-demo.com --firebase_secret '1234' --exclude 'settings/*, users/*/settings'
```

[Github Repo](https://github.com/sinisavukovic/firebase-export)

---

*Note:* Firebase has a [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data), so you can use any language to retrieve (export) data:

```
curl 'https://[PROJECT_ID].firebaseio.com/users/jack/name.json'
```

Here's an example curl request with filters

```
curl 'https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/dinosaurs.json?orderBy="height"&startAt=3&print=pretty'
```

Comment: I'm getting 
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at list (/home/jlam/.nvm/versions/node/v12.11.1/lib/node_modules/firebase-export/bin/firebase-export.js:29:14)`
with firebase-export

Comment: @JulienLamarche I don't see that error, but I think it's this issue: https://github.com/sinisavukovic/firebase-export/issues/2#issuecomment-466890517

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large JSON file then it is safe to download it using **Postman's** **Import** feature because downloading a large JSON file sometimes faces failure in the middle of the way. You just need to click **save the response** after the response is reached.
[image]