# Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to int in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am developing an app that fetches data from firebase into a recycler view.
But I am receiving an error in onStart of the application run

this the error that i am recieving.

```html
                                                                                                                     

    Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to int
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zze(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.parseSnapshot(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:147)
at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:136)
at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:176)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6477)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6510)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5453)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5719)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5558)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5554)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3694)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3110)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19161)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6118)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1723)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1275)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:650)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19161)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1630)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19161)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6118)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:91)
at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19161)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6118)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:223)
at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19161)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6118)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1723)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:788)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:648)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19161)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6118)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:223)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19161)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6118)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1723)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVer
```

**StreetDataFetcher.java**

this is class that retrives the data it contains all the getters,constructors.

```html
public class StreetDataFetcher {

     private String UserName;
     private String Long_Desc;
     private String Short_Desc;
     private String DateTime;
     private String VideoName;
     private String VideoPath;
     private String ProfileImage;
     private int  Likes;
     private int Views;

    public StreetDataFetcher( String userName, String long_Desc, String short_Desc, String dateTime, String videoName, String videoPath, String profileImage, int likes, int views ) {
        UserName = userName;
        Long_Desc = long_Desc;
        Short_Desc = short_Desc;
        DateTime = dateTime;
        VideoName = videoName;
        VideoPath = videoPath;
        ProfileImage = profileImage;
        Likes = likes;
        Views = views;
    }

    public int getLikes() {
        return Likes;
    }

    public int getViews() {
        return Views;
    }

    public StreetDataFetcher() {

    }

    public StreetDataFetcher( String profileImage ) {
        ProfileImage = profileImage;
    }

    public String getProfileImage() {
        return ProfileImage;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return UserName;
    }

    public void setUserName( String userName ) {
        UserName = userName;
    }

    public String getVideoName() {
        return VideoName;
    }

    public void setVideoName( String videoName ) {
        VideoName = videoName;
    }

    public String getVideoPath() {
        return VideoPath;
    }

    public void setVideoPath( String videoPath ) {
        VideoPath = videoPath;
    }

    public String getLong_Desc() {
        return Long_Desc;
    }

    public void setLong_Desc( String long_Desc ) {
        Long_Desc = long_Desc;
    }

    public String getShort_Desc() {
        return Short_Desc;
    }

    public void setShort_Desc( String short_Desc ) {
        Short_Desc = short_Desc;
    }

    public String getDateTime() {
        return DateTime;
    }

    public void setDateTime( String DateTime ) {
        DateTime = DateTime;
    }


}
```

**ViewHolder**

```html
    public static class StreetViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        TextView Username;
        TextView datee;
        TextView Title;
        TextView ShortDesc;
        ImageView Img1;
        Context ctx;
        de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView Img2;

        public StreetViewHolder( View itemView ) {
            super(itemView);
            ctx=itemView.getContext();
            Username=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.UsernameText);
            datee=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
            Title=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Title);
            ShortDesc=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ShortDescription);
            Img1=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.VideoName);
            Img2=(de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.ProfilePicture);
        }

        public void setTitle( String title ) {
            Title.setText(title);
        }


        public void setShortDesc( String shortDesc ) {
            ShortDesc.setText(shortDesc);
        }

        public void setUsername( String username ) {
            Username.setText(username);
        }


        public void setDate( String date ) {
            datee.setText(date.toString());
        }

        public void setVideoPath( String videoPath ) {
                MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever=new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoPath,new HashMap<String,String>());
                Bitmap bitmap=mediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(10000000);
                Img1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        public void setProfile( String profile ) {
            Picasso.with(ctx).load(profile).into(Img2);        }
    }
```

**RecyclerView**

```html
myRef1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Video_Upload").child("Street");
                myRef1.keepSynced(true);
                myRef1.orderByKey();
                rView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.StreetRecyclerView);
                rView.hasFixedSize();
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
                rView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                FBRA = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<StreetDataFetcher, Street_food.StreetViewHolder>(
                        StreetDataFetcher.class,
                        R.layout.card_recycler_view,
                        Street_food.StreetViewHolder.class,
                        myRef1
                ) {
                    @Override
                    protected void populateViewHolder( Street_food.StreetViewHolder viewHolder, StreetDataFetcher model, final int position ) {
                        viewHolder.setTitle(model.getVideoName());
                        viewHolder.setShortDesc(model.getShort_Desc());
                        viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUserName());
                        viewHolder.setDate(model.getDateTime());
                        viewHolder.setVideoPath(model.getVideoPath());
                        viewHolder.setProfile(model.getProfileImage());
                        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick( View v ) {
                                final String mref;
                                mref=FBRA.getRef(position).getKey().toString().trim();
                                Intent i=new Intent(getActivity(),StreetVideoView.class);
                                i.putExtra("position",mref);
                                startActivity(i);

                            }
                        });
                    }
                };

                rView.setAdapter(FBRA);
```

Firebase Structure

[firebase Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soGKq.png)

Comment: Can you post your datastructure as text, instead of an image. Also there seem to be some properties missing from your datastructure. Are they not there or simply not in the picture?

Comment: I only have the picture of structure

Comment: Also is your firebase package have latest version?

Comment: Yes it does actually my app was working alright last night but crashed today morning don't know why

Comment: You can [export your data in firebase console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182297/how-do-i-export-data-from-firebase-realtime-database). Currently you database image is not enough to see the problem because there is data missing

Comment: **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383687/how-can-i-retrieve-data-from-firebase-to-my-adapter/49384849)** is a recommended way in which you can retrieve data from a Firebase Realtime database and display it in a `RecyclerView` using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`.