# Firebase | Export collection data in CSV format using firebase console

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have query regarding the data export from Firebase Console. Can we export collection data in CSV format using Firebase console?
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can [export to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182297/how-do-i-export-data-from-firebase-realtime-database), then write your own code to convert that into whatever other format you want.  You can't export directly to any other format.