# Firebase: Exporting JSON Unable to export The size of data exported at a single location cannot exceed 256 MB

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I used to download a node of firebase real-time database every day to monitor some outputs by exporting the .JSON file for that node. The JSON file itself is about 8MB.

Recently, I started receiving an error:

"*Exporting JSON Unable to export The size of data exported at a single location cannot exceed 256 MB.Navigate to a smaller part of the database or use backups. Read more about limits*"

Can someone please explain why I keep getting this error, since the JSON file I exported just yesterday was only 8.1 MB large.

Comment: Are you using the dashboard to export? Have you tried exporting as explained in this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49529584/4633296

Comment: Same problem, one day small file, next day cannot download due to size, and it is not because it suddenly is much larger..

Answer (score 0):

I probably solved it! I disabled CORS addon in Chrome and suddenly it worked to export :)

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of this, you can use **Postman's** **Import** feature because downloading a large JSON file sometimes faces failure in the middle of the way using a browser from the dashboard of the firebase. You can put the traditional **cUrl** commands on it. You just need to click **save the response** after the response is reached. To get rid of complex authentication complexity, you make the `rule permission` of the firebase database to `read:true` until the download is complete thought you need to ensure security for this. Postman also needs sometimes to preview the JSON even freezing the UI but you don't need to be bothered with it.
[image]