# saving Firebase Realtime Database data into SQL table or NoSQL table

Tags: sql, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

dear firebase community,

I'm using Firebase realtime database to read temperature sensor data from Arduino.

I am able to read the data successfully.

However, I'm not sure if there is a setting in Firebase to store the data into SQL / NoSQL table with timestamp. For example:

Timestamp | Sensor 1 | Sensor 2
9/9/2020 | 9am | 25.6C | 30.1C
9/9/2020 | 10am | 22.3C | 32.2C
9/9/2020 | 11am | 22.2C | 31.2C

Just wondering if someone can point me to the right direction?

Thank you for your valuable feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no provided option or setting for exporting data in Realtime Database to any other type of database.  You can write your own program to read the database and send that to another database, or you [export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182297/how-do-i-export-data-from-firebase-realtime-database) the data and JSON and use some other tool or program to perform the copy.

It's up to you to find a tool that works for, if one exists.  Since recommendations for tools and software is off-topic for Stack Overflow, I suggest starting with a web search.

Comment: thank you. I understand now that i need export the data maybe to Node. Really appreciate your guidance :)