# How do I export data in each variable respectively from Firebase Realtime Database using command line

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, export, cls

I have already read these scripts
[How do I export data from Firebase Realtime Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182297/how-do-i-export-data-from-firebase-realtime-database)

but this method allow me to download whole data from indicated URL.

In my case, I just want to download from "https://*****.firebaseio.com/aaa/bbb/ccc", how can I download these data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer to the question you mentioned above actually should work for you. You should be able to write the desired path as part of url, but add ".json" in the end.

Answer (score 1):

I can solve this question by myself as follow.

```
curl -o '***<filename>***.json' https://***<firebase-url>***.firebaseio.com/aaa/bbb.json?auth=***<key>***
```