# Best way to export firebase into azure sql

Tags: firebase, azure, firebase-realtime-database, azure-sql

Using firebase for App Data - what is the best way to ETL this into Azure SQL so we can analyze better?  Have tried doing firebase->big query->azure data factory->azure sql and it just seems a bit clunky.  Have seen I could export to JSON then import to SQL perhaps.  Let me know if anyone has any best practices

Comment: Do you confirm that you use the Firebase Realtime Database and not Firestore.

Answer (score 1):

I have 3 ways for this :-

**WAY - 1:** [Export JSON from firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182297/how-do-i-export-data-from-firebase-realtime-database)

Like you said we can export JSON and import in our azure SQL
Go to the node that you want to export -> Click 3 dots `...` -> Export JSON.

**WAY - 2:** [Firebase Export Command](https://github.com/sinisavukovic/firebase-export)

You can use the node.js tool to export your JSON structure and import it to your SQL Database.

**WAY -3:** [Improvado (3rd part app)](https://improvado.io/connections/firebase-to-microsoft-azure-sql-database)

Extract your data from Firebase and automatically load it to a Microsoft Azure SQL Database.